# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar por fechas en SQL?

Tags: sql

Lo que sucede es que tengo una tabla y quiero filtrar por fechas algunos productos. La tabla que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
create table producto(
id_producto int primary KEY NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre_producto varchar(50),
descripcion_producto varchar(100),
fecha_creacion TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NULL,
fecha_vencimiento_producto DATE NOT NULL,
id_tipo_producto int,
id_usuario int
);
```

Y la consulta que estoy realizando es esta:

```
SELECT * FROM producto where 'fecha_vencimiento_producto' between 2019-10-02 and 2019-10-31
```

También lo intenté de esta otra manera

```
SELECT * FROM producto where 'fecha_vencimiento_producto' between 20191001 and 20191031
```

pero no he logrado que me salga el producto que tengo registrado para vencer el `2019-10-27`. ¿Alguien sabe por qué se da esto? Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Puedes añadir  cual RDBMS estás usando? Tengo la impresión de que es Oracle, pero no estoy seguro. La sintaxis varía de uno a otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las fechas debes ponerlas entre comillas.

```
SELECT * FROM producto where fecha_vencimiento_producto between '2019-10-02' and '2019-10-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer no estas definiendo bien el rango de fecha debes quitar comillas a `fecha_vencimiento_producto` y agregarle comillas a tus fechas de rango, ademas utilíza la función `convert()` para convertirlas a fecha.

**Ejemplo:**

```
SELECT * FROM producto where fecha_vencimiento_producto between convert(date,'2019-10-02' and convert(date,'2019-10-31')
```